# How to create a mod-100 counter with two 7-segment displays using JK flip-flops?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, counter

Here is my whole diagram.
There is no output while also clock is ticking...

I think there is a problem with the counter, but I can't figure it out.

I use rising-edge flipflops.

[image: whole thing while clock= 0]

[image: whole thing while clock= 1]

[image: counter= 0]

[image: counter= 1]

[image: decoder= 0/1]

Comment: I hope you will add your schematic soon.

Comment: Since this looks like homework we will expect you to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself. Show us all of your work: truth tables, state tables, etc. Describe **exactly** what "doesn't work" means. Then you can ask a **specific** question.

Comment: You proably need a power-on reset to set the flip-flops to a known initial state.

Comment: *I added clock in place but no outputs.* - Do you see the clock changing?

Comment: Also your NAND output connection doesn't look good. Delete the line and reconnect.

Comment: BTW, it is hard to see on this screenshot. Thich input on the FFs the NAND output is connected to?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's connected to the asynchronous reset input (marked 0)

Comment: @EugeneSh. the NAND output is drawn one grid square longer than it needs to be, so it overlaps the gate by one square. This does count as a valid 3-way connection (see there is a green dot)

Comment: Is it active low or active high?

Comment: @EugeneSh. active high, like most things in Logisim (it tries not to confuse you). So, in fact, there is the problem!

Comment: So, the whole thing is in a constant reset.

Comment: @AryanJR Why haven't you read my answer? Because the flip flops are positive edge triggered, for an up counter, you must use flip-flops with Q-bar outputs on them and connect the Q-bar outputs to the clock input of the next higher stage. Then you read the count output from the Q outputs.

Comment: I solved... Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are positive edge triggered flip-flops then you need to come off the Q-bar outputs into the next clock inputs for an up counter. Come off the Q outputs as shown in your diagram if the flip-flops are negative edge triggered. If the flip-flops shown are positive edge triggered then the counter will count down from 0 direct to 15 and immediately reset back to 0.